# I want change directory and run command in fabric

Tags: python, django, fabric

I want to change directory and when I run command with cd('myApp') I get:

```
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

I have this code:

```
def example():
    local('sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev')
    local('pip install MySQL-python')
    local('sudo apt-get install apache2')
    with cd('myApp'):
        run('pwd')
        run('python manage.py syncdb --no-initial-data')
        run('python manage.py migrate')
    print(green('DONE.'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official tutorial, the error specifies that you have not specified a connection in your fabfile for it to deploy. Please check [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/tutorial.html#making-connections).

Other than that, in the cd method(used along side the with statement), use full path like

```
with cd('/path/to/directory/myApp')
```

rather than just the 'myApp'. Even if it is just '/myApp'. It improves readability and also makes sure that that is the path you wish to go.